# Visualizar las tareas por realizar a partir del dia de hoy ,rango de hora 18:00 a 8:00 del siguiente día mediante JQL Jira

Tags: jira, jql

Trato de obtener todas las tareas que fueron creadas apartir de un rango de horas de 18:00 a 8:00 del siguiente dia, trabajando con Jira por medio de Jql.

Esta instrucción es la que estoy realizando

> project = "prueba" AND created >='2022-02-10 18:00' AND created <=
> '2022-02-11 8:00' order by created DESC

Al ejecutar el query obtengo los ticket creados  del día de hoy y las de ayer, como puedo validar, solo la hora..?

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente usa la fecha del día de ayer hoy y usa el operador `OR`, acostumbra definir primero el limite inferior.

Esto obtendrá las tareas creadas en tu proyecto "prueba" el día de ayer y hoy creadas entre las 8:00 y las 18:00 horas:

> project = "prueba" AND (created >='2022-02-10 8:00' AND created <= '2022-02-10 18:00' OR created >= '2022-02-11 8:00' AND created <='2022-02-11 18:00')

Comment: Una consulta existe alguna forma de crear el filtro tomando solo los rangos de hora para no estar modificando todos los dias las fechas.?

Comment: Si, se puede usar startOfDay(), si quieres agrega otra pregunta.

Comment: Podrias brindarme como aplicar startOfDay() en el siguiente Query por favor. 


project = "prueba" AND (created >='2022-02-10 8:00' AND created <= '2022-02-10 18:00' OR created >= '2022-02-11 8:00' AND created <='2022-02-11 18:00')